# How long to blob urls served by the app engine remain valid?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I was wondering if anyone knew how long image urls served back from the google app engine blob store remain valid for?

I have been tracking on url that i served [an image](http://lh3.ggpht.com/n2vefqV64BCW_V2g0EBFdD8heJmDE3Iu0FXXY2lK0rNSEVrIybE4iQho5KVSjUlSi9IpoKKEo11jW5pk26DGA7uJ) from the blob store on 1/3/13 and its still there.

I am ask specifically so i can cache the image url instead of attempting to serve it repeatedly. If i did this i would still check if the image is there, but how often would i need to check that

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They remain valid until either you

a. call [delete_serving_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions), or 
b. [delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions) the underling blob.

Comment: Thanks! is there any reason to delete the urls? (best practice wise) , or, if i know what the urls are just,should i just persist them directly...

Comment: only if you don't want them to serve any more - it counts towards your outgoing bandwidth. you should always be persisting the URL for a blob if you can, rather than calling get_serving_url over and over.

Comment: thanks! i will make some changes, i was just concerned with persisting the url and then having to check to make sure it still was valid. Obviously anyway i can shrink outgoing data i want to use.