# PHP Google Cloud Storage Tools getImageServingUrl returns old image

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have PHP application running on google app engine which uses google cloud storage to store images.

I'm displaying images using `CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl` and the url is successfully pointed to images. I re-size the image using `=sXXX` format.

```
e.g: http://lh3.ggpht.com/AddEfddJKeiesklEaldaooea9as9e7de=s144
```

The problem is once I delete the previous image and replace it with another image using the same image name and **it displays the older image**. Even though I clear browser cache it doesn't solve. But when I remove =sXXX part from the url, it points to the new image without any problem at all. How can I overcome this?

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: How did you get the CloudStorageTools to work? I tried adding it in using the code Google provide, but i get the error "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CloudStorageTools' not found" when trying to create an upload URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now a lot familiar with GAE PHP but I ll help a bit.

A **serving url** is persistent until (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331245/how-long-to-blob-urls-served-by-the-app-engine-remain-valid)):

> a. call delete_serving_url, or
>
> b. delete the underling blob.

Now I've searched and the function `CloudStorageTools::deleteImageServingUrl()` exists for PHP so try calling that and then create a new one.

Comment: This doesnt' work for me. Calling deleteImageServingUrl before getting other url from getImageServingUrl doesnt solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"?".microtime()` to the URL generated by `getImageServingUrl` to force refresh.