# Google Cloud Storage getImageServingUrl returns the wrong image

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Storage to store user uploaded images. 
I use this Google App Engine api PHP function to create a url that serve the image through a Google service.

```
CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($image_file, $options);
```

This service returns a public url to the image. This url takes some arguments that can be appended to the end of the url, which allows me to return different versions of the image. This could be a resized or cropped version of the image.

My problem is that this service does not always return the correct image.

Let me give you an example:

This is the url that is returned from the service. The problem is that this is not the correct image. It is not even one of my images.
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2oBRlAM8FZBuDm1Byp8fGAZhEwVSg2PlxRWWU2k3vNCn-DJwYWL41w2VnAZGfnLeHrJ-U4KgSSoEKpoduZ8QpRO9xNXRcAOoMrnZabSX6WMF

If I append some arguments at the end of the url, for example *=w800* which should give me a resized version of the image with the width of 800px, then the service returns the correct image.
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2oBRlAM8FZBuDm1Byp8fGAZhEwVSg2PlxRWWU2k3vNCn-DJwYWL41w2VnAZGfnLeHrJ-U4KgSSoEKpoduZ8QpRO9xNXRcAOoMrnZabSX6WMF=w800

Until now I have discovered this problem on three images. I find it really alarming that the service sometimes is returning someone else's images.

Have any of you experienced a simular problem?

I am a bit worried about this problem, since I was hoping to use this service in a ios and android app that we are developing at my company.
I know that the problem is not related to caching on my computer since this is happening on multiple computers and mobile devices.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670281/php-google-cloud-storage-tools-getimageservingurl-returns-old-image.

Comment: It is not exactly the same because in my case I did not replace one of my own images with another image using the same filename. The problem is that I get a image that does not exist in my storage bucket. The image must come from someone else's storage bucket, and this concerns me.

Comment: @JonasVinther would you mind emailing me: mcdonald at firebase dot com so I can help debug this issue?

Comment: Have you solved this issue somehow because i'm facing same issue currently & couldn't find any proper solution. Any help would be great